# Value is not updating after async method resume

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await

Looking at this code :

```
public class SharedData
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AAA();
}

async Task BBB(SharedData data)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    MessageBox.Show(data.Value.ToString()); //<---- I always see 0 here,
    data.Value = data.Value + 1;
}

async Task<int> AAA()
{
    SharedData data = new SharedData();
    var task1 = BBB(data);
    var task2 = BBB(data);
    var task3 = BBB(data);

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
    MessageBox.Show(data.Value.ToString());  //<--- this does show 3
    return data.Value;
}
```

This is a GUI (windows forms ) application  , which means that there is only one thread executing each line of code.

All `BBB(data)` invocations are invoked very quick  without waiting.
Each `BBB` invocation get's into the BBB `method` , sees `await` which doesn't complete and returns ( to AAA).

Now ,  when one second (approx) is elapsed, all continuations are happening *in the GUI thread*.

**Question**

Continuations doesn't happen simultaneously because it's a GUI thread .
So a previous statement of :

```
data.Value = data.Value + 1;
```

Must have occurred.

In other words ,

I know that all `BBB`s are invoked with the same initial value of `data` , but the continuations doesn't happens concurrently

The GUI thread must run eventually:

<sub>continuation #1</sub>

```
 MessageBox.Show(data.Value.ToString()); 
 data.Value = data.Value + 1; //So this basically should do 0-->1
....
```

<sub>continuation #2</sub>

```
 MessageBox.Show(data.Value.ToString()); // Why data.Value still "0" ??
 data.Value = data.Value + 1;  
....
```

<sub>continuation #3</sub>

```
 MessageBox.Show(data.Value.ToString()); // Why data.Value still "0" ??
 data.Value = data.Value + 1;
```

It looks like the continuations are scheduled not as a whole but as shared quanta ?

Comment: @Eser I don't understand , each continuation has the gui thread for himself. there are **no** other threads involved here. why lock ?  This is not(!) running in a threadpool thread which means there is no context to preserve ( and each continuation can run in another threadpool thread)..

Comment: Change `BBB` to accept and use the delay value: `async Task BBB(SharedData data, int delay)`, then pass different values rather than the same `1`. Wondering why now you're seeing three message boxes at once, rather than one at a time? :)

Comment: @Noseratio Yes I do wonder :-) can you please explain ? [This code](http://i.imgur.com/pWUXCXW.png) shows 3 MSgBox together rather than 1 at a time (like in my example). Can you explain why ?

Comment: Blame the underlying Win32 `MessageBox` API for this. If you used `Form.ShowDialog` you'd see all 3 boxes in the correct 1-2-3 order. With `MessageBox`, the other two boxes are still there, just not visible. They did have started their nested modal message loops, one from another, because `await Task.Delay(1000)` continuations still gets pumped. A nested message loop starts, caused by whichever continuation wins the race, so the code which shows the window doesn't start until that message loop is terminated.

Comment: @Noseratio Sorry I still don't understand why when they all quickly finished by the same delay — I see one at a time , while putting a different delay(1,2,3) — I see all 3 of them one on the top of the other. But I think it's getting out of the scope of this question. [I will ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573672/async-awaits-continuations-bursts-behave-differently).

Comment: Royi, @StephenCleary's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32574999/1768303) explains it in much better details than my comment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens because you're using `MessageBox.Show` for debug prints and showing a modal message box blocks the code-flow but doesn't block the UI thread (otherwise you couldn't interact with the message box).

So, when the first continuation is "blocked" by showing a message box the next continuation can run and then the third. They are all "blocked" by showing the message boxes but the UI thread itself isn't.

That's why they all show `0` and only when you release the message boxes they can continue running and increase the variable.

You can see that if you print the value using `Console.WriteLine` before showing the message box:

```
async Task BBB(SharedData data)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Console.WriteLine(data.Value);
    MessageBox.Show(data.Value.ToString());
    data.Value = data.Value + 1;
}
```

You'll notice that `0` is printed 3 times by all the continuations exactly after 1 second and not after you dismiss the message boxes.

Basically, **the continuations run concurrently, but not in parallel using the same thread** because of the `MessageBox.Show` in them.

If you use `Console.WriteLine` instead of `MessageBox.Show` you will see that the value is incremented one at a time:

```
async Task BBB(SharedData data)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Console.WriteLine(data.Value);
    data.Value = data.Value + 1;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: The second paragraph is not clear ( to me). : _when the first continuation is "blocked" by showing a message box the next continuation can run and then the third_ ? Can you please show the steps ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir showing a modal message box blocks the current code flow, but it doesn't do that by blocking the thread (otherwise the app will freeze). That means the first continuation is stuck, but the next one can run on the UI thread.

Comment: So when I see the first message box , at that time , there are 2 continuations which already invoking `MessageBox.Show(data.Value.ToString());` with the NOT ALREADY INCREASED VALUE ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir exactly. This is how the message loop works. [Here's](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f37a652-b558-4342-ade9-ad5ce68c9d01/why-does-showdialog-not-block-the-ui-thread-completely?forum=netfxbcl) a similar issue on the MSDN forums.

Comment: @RoyiNamir It blocks the flow, but not the thread itself. It can't block the thread itself because that is the thread that draws the message box. If the thread would have been blocked the app will freeze and be unresponsive.

Comment: if use `MessageBox.Show((data.Value++).ToString()); ` to instand of `MessageBox.Show(data.Value.ToString())` and remove `data.Value = data.Value + 1`,it will display in this order:2 ,1 , 0,why?

Comment: @SkyFang because that operator increments the value before showing the message box.

Comment: And also if you add some task after  `AAA()`, it will show another `MessageBox`,it means there will be 2 `MessageBox` showed, I can't understand

Comment: @SkyFang keep in mind that `AAA` returns a task and is not awaited.

Comment: @i3arnon,yes, I know that operator increments the value before showing the message box,my question is that why this order:2,1,0,not 0,1,2?

Comment: @SkyFang That isn't the order of the messageboxes. They are just one of top of the other. That's why they open in a diagonal.